# Write to sql server of enum type? DropDownListFor| ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

- I have a dropdownlist in view. It gets values ​​from the enum, because I can't do otherwise. (If someone gives me an idea / example of how to do it, I will gladly accept it)
- I'm just writing this application, and I have a question whether the current way I did it, or this way can be saved to the database?

**Database**

> Column  Name ||||| Data Type |||||   Allow Nulls
>
> PrzyczynaNieobecnosci | varchar(20)  | true

**Model**

```
public partial class Karta_Model
{
   public Urlopy? PrzyczynaNieobecnosci { get; set; }
}

public enum Urlopy
{
    a, 
    b, 
    c
}

public partial class ParentView
{
    public List<Karta_Model> Model1 { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
@using AppEcp.Models
@model ParentView

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model1[nr_rows].PrzyczynaNieobecnosci, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(Urlopy))), "  ", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/chxcUO)

**Model**

```
public partial class Karta_Model
{
   public List<string> PrzyczynaNieobecnosci { get; set; }
}

public partial class ParentView
{
    public List<Karta_Model> Model1 { get; set; }
}
```

**In Controller:**

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new ParentView()
        { 
            Model1 = new  List<Karta_Model> 
                     { 
                       new Karta_Model { PrzyczynaNieobecnosci = new List<string> { "a", "b"}}, 
                       new Karta_Model { PrzyczynaNieobecnosci = new List<string> { "c", "d"}}
                     }
        });
    }
```

**In View**

You should get the correct number of item in the list like below

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model1[0].PrzyczynaNieobecnosci, new SelectList(Model.Model1[0].PrzyczynaNieobecnosci), "  ", new { @class = "form-control" })

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Model1[0].PrzyczynaNieobecnosci, new SelectList(Model.Model1[1].PrzyczynaNieobecnosci), "  ", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: ie it works for me, but will it write to the database?

Comment: Could you please give me: **1.** Your sample data of `PrzyczynaNieobecnosci` in table? **2.** Are you using EF or ADO to connect database? **3.** Why you want to use `enum` type instead of list of string ?

Comment: 1. Yes, in table. 2. EF, 3. otherwise I can't
 do dropdownlist

Comment: I've just updated my answer (re-design data structure), please take a look at. https://dotnetfiddle.net/chxcUO

Comment: near var userDetailsAU = _ecpContext.AC_Merge_V.FirstOrDefault(f => f.ADlogin == userName);      |||||   Karta_Model.PrzyczynaNieobecnosci' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'List<string>' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'.”

Comment: You should give us your sample data, table and model class. your question needs more details. Sorry, I did my best.